# How do I use multiple lines in a single layer in mapbox-gl-js?

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

Mapbox uses source and layer to draw circle, line etc on the map. I have difficulty in understanding the source and layer id. As i can see through examples and tutorials that, a layer defines how the data should be displayed on the map, and a source defines the data for that layer.

I could have multiple sources and layers on the map.

I want to create multiple line layer on the map, so i did this.

```js
map.addSource('11111111',{
                'type':'geojson',
                'data':{
                    'type':'Feature',
                    'properties':{},
                    'geometry':{
                        'type':'LineString',
                        'coordinates':[
                            [76.993894,31.781929]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            });
    
            map.addLayer({
                'id': '11111111',
                'type': 'line',
                'source': '11111111',
                'layout': {
                'line-join': 'round',
                'line-cap': 'round'
                },
                'paint': {
                'line-color': 'red',
                'line-width': 4
                }
            });
```

Here addSource method take an source id `(11111111)`.
How can i add multiple line sources in one layer, because each sources must  have unique id.

Comment: I couldn't understand "How can i add multiple line sources in one layer, because each sources must have unique id." Are you able to express this differently? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to add multiple line on the map at the same time. Each source should have an unique id as mapbox docs. A layer also require the source id to render line. So, my question is, can i add multiple sources on one layer. I don't want to create a seperate layer fo each source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have multiple lines in a single source by using a [feature collection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.3).

```
map.addSource('multiple-lines-source', {
  'type': 'geojson',
  'data': {
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'features': [
      {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'properties': {},
        'geometry': {
          'type': 'LineString',
          'coordinates': [
            [-104.4140625, 43.32517767999296],
            [-58.35937499999999, -9.79567758282973]
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'properties': {},
        'geometry': {
          'type': 'LineString',
          'coordinates': [
            [20.390625, 10.487811882056695],
            [15.468749999999998, 49.83798245308484]
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/oh8Ld1ry/1/